# Problems installing a specific version of pandas (0.21.0) in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pip

I am trying to install a specific version of pandas, but it gives me the following error that I don't know what it means in specific, it is very long, just put the beginning, I don't know if there is any solution other than installing a newer version of python

I do not place the entire error response since it is very long.

```
    pip install pandas==0.21.0

    2019-10-08T11:21:12 Collecting pandas==0.21.0
    2019-10-08T11:21:12   1 location(s) to search for versions of pandas:
    2019-10-08T11:21:12   * https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
    2019-10-08T11:21:12   Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
    2019-10-08T11:21:15   Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/8e/057ebd80a3b6dcda154dd6878744fc5549832a484e72bc4189b8d782be75/pandas-0.1.tar.gz#sha256=8d65c67df35e181997c6ede3a0721f8989d1928c9be4fc91ecd5ced311ecd3b6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.1
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/bc/e5e0373d8567df741c947c7c60afc9af71d16052937762c15bda9f0aa360/pandas-0.1.win32-py2.5.exe#sha256=1b25975c12ee09cb029d77dee1e6f500a6b88bc0cf995d72f3edd9b3c1d96eb0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/c7/897504696446c565fa578ff814ada3a8d954c5c13107688252e94b86542f/pandas-0.2beta.tar.gz#sha256=e9ab36616cc350d536e538d3d7a944f7628f3fcbad703e28bb1cff4d2d0a1bca (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.2beta
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/8e/29766514baf2b15a5d9bddcd7e57f00b33b842681f07f63478ecf441e454/pandas-0.2b1.tar.gz#sha256=1ec2a7fc565782253a71815c518defe24127bc6ef4a0fc8fc0ef7d5ad9e8f980 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.2b1
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/aa/282a80536b64714afb526539e5b70de5ec836226a7031fc4db5c593e7ebd/pandas-0.2.tar.gz#sha256=a1352d756d50288de881de0d94d853266cd0149072c32ec24b05c428b1669837 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.2
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/81/d46942d265d6a18bff5809bcc0e41b949876a51831a7bff5f90834f750c7/pandas-0.3.0.beta.tar.gz#sha256=26b2198b96afa7df062907a362749dcb677228324f7155ee59271aaa162e4966 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.3.0.beta
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/40/283994433948068a7f287132f785ea17ba29cd0abed4a2d30f6ea304631d/pandas-0.3.0.beta.win-amd64-py2.6.exe#sha256=82f89471ab5c3d52bc77ad7eacd6fc59c9d75be722300d74967a9ccc29b2484b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/d1/7b22e8c6895ecd88d92f9bd4e458350f41fa0fc33c931e5c0a15da108331/pandas-0.3.0.beta.win32-py2.5.exe#sha256=fa6d44c1fedcc26c16e1fca344e7d9f21eab5a94d101444b434462ef4d19d42e (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/66/f9dc524164e87f5665050e30d72be42b85166faca242b7b7a238462a60e3/pandas-0.3.0.beta.win32-py2.6.exe#sha256=820486ca5fd96d82a0282735d6f3c408526250f93cce3e0928a68ec726382952 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/99/fb333218acf61308d81ebdde50e53c75c92073bc675a52fffbe5727f8668/pandas-0.3.0.beta.win32-py2.7.exe#sha256=065531d4729af2248b8952a482af5656498650efb65f2c9ca82d24a40c079fe7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/a2/8ff863d0d92ecef3e54412f5e0d6cf488df5570a1558124fa013fce15bb8/pandas-0.3.0.beta2.tar.gz#sha256=73a454d9abbe018dba55552f1f85a9691a9e383151d25274c8e19ef0effeacd8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.3.0.beta2
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/e1/ed57539a7748c05ffcd43798ba72be9340f12492677e33d16baf8f0e2f93/pandas-0.3.0.beta2.win32-py2.5.exe#sha256=f023504a33b2fd43a43672b6f170799fae5ca9e11feb3de080677c446d30be20 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/c4/afde6d2d75c9adcc550f959e0732e4753ab2d456fa2653891c8d44882582/pandas-0.3.0.beta2.win32-py2.6.exe#sha256=a5e3f539105a8da5884c2120dcffe5abc485cfee5d2bca184586f265e9c3c24a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/5e/bf1d23b7aced0f940b29a165471917bf836cbdb17aa5e172b285445336f9/pandas-0.3.0.beta2.win32-py2.7.exe#sha256=a17f39073484cc2b2d4218be52677765d55c520f3fb6675a270db3151ee18560 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d9/5bc8c823cc0d7922e613fdba43c39cba440d30bef2961d9c3f6978db1b1d/pandas-0.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=4e853e7aa2f4ef62c44d45dacc396dda786b8996c521f61b34fdbf832d109f5e (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/), version: 0.3.0
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/a7/20e3d2a3ed84dc696da4e6b761883afe5e6a35597c4541018a81b21f3cf7/pandas-0.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.exe#sha256=7d04f2c8e5e3a204e4da1a50c3a4665c3f2585f7bc9fcc55d7e3f223c482f218 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/7b/0171453a1ddf52c9c501e4f6c96334c96834bccc8865a5b0d6867f11abb4/pandas-0.3.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe#sha256=c9d3fb02f029fa64a491e0b155ab9801517b8aec1392a987a1a4b8b8f5a5e981 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    2019-10-08T11:21:15     Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/9f/f236843423e3291182d0eb1e233459b7f925de8afaba9eb1322a2f7f2259/pandas-0.3.0.win32-py2.5.e
```

Comment: [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers must be **a practical, answerable problem unique to software development.**

Comment: I would suggest using [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)